# Migrating to Play 2.5

Tags: playframework, ebean

I am trying to migrate a small project which I started on Play! 2.2 to 2.5. However, I running into the problem with Ebeans, and the migration of Ebeans to a separate module.

So I tried to start a clean project, and add EBeans according to the documentation, but I still get the following message:

```
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/user/Documents/Java/xyz/project
Play ebean module has been replaced with an external Play ebean plugin.
See https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24 for details.
```

My **build.sbt**:

```
name := "y2kbooking"

version := "1.0"

lazy val `y2kbooking` = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq( javaJdbc , javaEbean , cache , javaWs )

unmanagedResourceDirectories in Test <+=  baseDirectory ( _ /"target/web/public/test" )
```

(note that Idea shows PlayEbean in red, as it doesn't know the module?)

**Plugins.sbt**:

```
logLevel := Level.Warn

resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")
```

**build.properties**:

```
sbt.version=0.13.8
```

**application.conf**:

```
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
db.default.user=sa
db.default.password="defaultlogonpassword"

ebean.default= ["models.*"]
```

Is there something I am missing?
I create the projected with IDEA and run it with IDEA Scale plugin 1.5.4.

[EDIT:]
I also tried butting the **sbt-play-ebean** **addSbtPlugin** before the **stb-plugin**. This however gives the following error:

```
Error:Error while importing SBT project:
...
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:65)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:65)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:48)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:32)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:24)
    at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:53)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:129)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:36)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:19)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:44)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: $bc978b751097ebe513a6$
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Invalid response.
```

[EDIT 2:]

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq( javaJdbc , javaEbean , cache , javaWs )
```

I think I missed the fact that 'javaEbean' was still in the libraryDependencies, and that might have been the cause. However, removing it does not give the migration warning, but the similar exception as in the edit above about the ClassNotFound:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: $0b93c53b7f37eaeb2c7f$
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.AbstractFileClassLoader.findClass(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:83)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:344)
    at sbt.compiler.Eval$.getModule(Eval.scala:471)
    at sbt.compiler.Eval$.getValue(Eval.scala:462)
    at sbt.compiler.Eval$$anonfun$4.apply(Eval.scala:97)
    at sbt.compiler.Eval$$anonfun$4.apply(Eval.scala:97)
    at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$evaluateDslEntry$1.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:185)
    at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$evaluateDslEntry$1.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:183)
    at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$evaluateSbtFile$1$$anonfun$11.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:128)
    at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$evaluateSbtFile$1$$anonfun$11.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:128)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$evaluateSbtFile$1.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:128)
    at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$evaluateSbtFile$1.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:122)
    at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$loadSettingsFile$1(Load.scala:712)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1$1.apply(Load.scala:717)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1$1.apply(Load.scala:716)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:58)
    at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1(Load.scala:716)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadFiles$1$2.apply(Load.scala:723)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadFiles$1$2.apply(Load.scala:723)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at sbt.Load$.loadFiles$1(Load.scala:723)
    at sbt.Load$.discoverProjects(Load.scala:734)
    at sbt.Load$.discover$1(Load.scala:545)
    at sbt.Load$.loadTransitive(Load.scala:574)
    at sbt.Load$.loadProjects$1(Load.scala:442)
    at sbt.Load$.loadUnit(Load.scala:446)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$18$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Load.scala:281)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$18$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Load.scala:281)
    at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:91)
    at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:90)
    at sbt.BuildLoader.apply(BuildLoader.scala:140)
    at sbt.Load$.loadAll(Load.scala:334)
    at sbt.Load$.loadURI(Load.scala:289)
    at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:285)
    at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:276)
    at sbt.Load$.apply(Load.scala:130)
    at sbt.Load$.buildPluginDefinition(Load.scala:821)
    at sbt.Load$.buildPlugins(Load.scala:787)
    at sbt.Load$.plugins(Load.scala:775)
    at sbt.Load$.loadUnit(Load.scala:431)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$18$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Load.scala:281)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$18$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Load.scala:281)
    at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:91)
    at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:90)
    at sbt.BuildLoader.apply(BuildLoader.scala:140)
    at sbt.Load$.loadAll(Load.scala:334)
    at sbt.Load$.loadURI(Load.scala:289)
    at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:285)
    at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:276)
    at sbt.Load$.apply(Load.scala:130)
    at sbt.Load$.defaultLoad(Load.scala:36)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:481)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:475)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:475)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:58)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:58)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:60)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:60)
    at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:92)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
    at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:184)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:98)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:91)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:70)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:65)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:65)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:48)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:32)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:24)
    at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:53)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:129)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:36)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:19)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:44)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: $0b93c53b7f37eaeb2c7f$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove it from the dependencies. Change your library dependencies to this:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq( javaJdbc , cache , javaWs )
```